# Differentiating types with templates

Tags: c++

I want to use the Map function to be able to take in 2 sets of data.
One set will be a dictionary of sorts. It will take in a word (the domain) and the definition (range).

The other set will be an Employee look up. Map needs to take in an employee id(Domain) and employee information (the range).

I want the map function to be able to handle Domain and Range values for either dictionary or employee.

The trouble in running into is:
I have 4 arrays for storing words, definitions, ids, and employee.
When I call map along with the filename for both the dictionary and employee in my executive class how can I have map store info into a specific array depending on what type of info is passed into the class.

Here is a link if my explanation wasn't quite good enough:
https://people.eecs.ku.edu/~jrmiller/Courses/268/Fall2019/Labs/Lab02.html

```
#include "Map.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

template <Typename Domain, Typename Range>
Map<Domain, Range>::Map(string fileName) {
  ifstream inFile;
  inFile.open(fileName);
  inFile >> numEntries;
  wordArray = new Domain[numEntries];
  defArray = new Range[numEntries];
  idArray = new Domain[numEntries];
  empArray = new Range[numEntries];
}

Map<Domain, Range>::add(Domain d, Range r, int position){
  wordArray[position] = d;
  defArray[position] = r;
  idArray[position] = d;
  empArray[position] = r;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to store both information in the same class? Isn't the point of your templates to have two separate maps - one for words/definitions, and the other one for id/information?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Indeed,.. and the `Map` in the link only has `Domain* dArray; Range* rArray;`.

Comment: We are supposed to use 2 instances of Map but create only one Map class. Hence why I'm having this issue

Comment: @TedLyngmo Right, but the goal is to instantiate 2 instances of this template class. So maybe I could just use 2 arrays but I'm not sure how I would go about doing that.

Comment: You should probably stick with the `Map` definition you got in the assignment (although it uses raw pointers) and work it out from there. Hint: Each time you use a class template with new template parameters a new class is created.

Comment: @TedLyngmo our teacher said the definition it provides is only a basic outline/example of how a Map class would be structured. It doesn't mean we have to or are necessarily supposed to do it specifically how it is written there.

Comment: I am afraid, you'd have to ask for clarifications from your professor. The task is sufficiently vague.

Comment: You may want to go back to the lecture explaining templates, because it's going to be difficult to explain it well here. Templates are pretty much a type substition mechanism - when you instatiate `Map` with let's say `<int, std::string>`, `dArray` will have type `int*` and `rArray` will have type `std::string*`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen right! I understand that part. Once I instantiate Map in my exec class with parameters for dictionary how will i again instantiate that class for employee and still use the same array to hold both sets of domains and ranges

Comment: How would you do that without templates? Let's say the task is to create two classes - `MapDictionary` and `MapEmployees`. If you did that, you'd soon find out that the code in both classes is identical, except for the type of `dArray` and `rArray`. Once you notice that, the next step is these types templates and suddenly you have a nice working template class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of answering your question as a whole I will give you an example to demonstrate where you are going wrong.

Suppose you want to have a `Store` that can hold any value of a certain type and it has a `check` method that lets you check if a given value equals the one in the store. We want this to work for strings and for integers.

```
template <typename T>
struct Store {
    T value;
    Store(const T& value) : value(value) {}
    bool check(const T& x) { return x == value; }
};
```

As you see, I didnt have to mention `std::string` or `int` at all. Also I didnt have to use 2 members, just because later we want to use two different types. Instead we now can instantiate the template for two different types:

```
Store<int> s{3};
bool c = s.check(3); // true

Store<std::string> t{"foo"};
bool d = t.check("foo");
```

Note that `Store<int>` and `Store<std::string>` are two distinct types. One has a `int` member, the other has a `std::string` member.

Similar in your exercise, your `Map` does not need member for each type you want to use it for later. The easiest case for templates is when the template code can be completely agnostic of what the actual types later will be and it seems like this is what this exercise is trying to reach for.

Comment: This helps a lot with the concept of templates! However, then my second question is: since Domain values for both dictionary and employee and being stored in the same array when I later access this array how can I access the different sets of domains and ranges. Edit: I'm a noob at this and stared at it long enough to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you say they are stored in the same array? You will have one `Map` for the `Dictionary` and one `Map` for the `Employee`s

Comment: @FezPaudel not sure what you mean, i tried to do some guessing and added a `check` method. A getter would be `T getValue() { return value; }`. Simply write the code but instead of mentioning the actual type you put the template parameter

Answer (score 0):

> The trouble in running into is: I have 4 arrays for storing words, definitions, ids, and employee.

So, I think you misunderstand the template design of your map.

The point of the template is that you do not care about what the Domain and Range mean. You only care about how they interact with each other. Namely, for every Domain, you have a corresponding Range value. You don't care that they are employees or dictionary words. That is the job for the higher level. You only care about keeping them in pairs, sorted, or other things related to your map.

> [S]ince Domain values for both dictionary and employee and being stored in the same array when I later access this array how can I access the different sets of domains and ranges

You're forgetting something: You have 2 instances. They are not stored in the same array. Domain1 is stored in Instance1, and Domain2 is stored in Instance2, etc. The same thing is true for the ranges. So, what ends up happening is when you have an instance:

```
Map</*template parameters*/> Employees;
```

You know that all the things stored in the Domain array are employee ids, for instance, and the Range is the employee names.

On the other hand, if you have another instance:

```
Map</*template parameters*/> Dictionary;
```

You know that the Domain array holds the word and the Range array holds the definition.

See? They are actually separate when you go the next level up. Thus, there is no reason to worry have 4 arrays at that level. You should only need 2.

Answer (score -1):

Your `Map` class should contain only 2 arrays and not 4 arrays. Because your Map will be mapping the `domain` to the `range`. So you should have `domainArray` and `rangeArray`. Now this domain and range will vary depending on the instantiation of Map type whether it is instantiated with `word/definition` or `id/employee`

So the should look like following:

```
template <Typename Domain, Typename Range>
class Map{
   ...
   Domain *domainArray; // Decide whether it can be static array or needs to be dynamic
   Range *rangeArray;
};

Map<Domain, Range>::add(Domain d, Range r, int position){
  domainArray[position] = d;
  rangeArray[position] = r;
}

Domain Map<Domain, Range>::getKey(int position){
  return domainArray[position];
}

Range Map<Domain, Range>::getValue(int position){
  return rangeArray[position];
}

int main()
{
   Map<int, EmployeeInfo> employeeMapping;
   Map<std::string, std::string> wordMeaningMapping; // Assuming both word and meanings are simple strings.

   EmployeeInfo emp;
   int id = 10;
   employeeMapping.add(id, emp, 0);

   std::string word = "apple";
   std::string meaning = "A fruit";
   wordMeaningMapping.add(word, meaning, 0);

   employeeMapping.getKey(0); // Will return 10
   wordMeaningMapping.getKey(0); // Will return "apple"
}
```

Normally, items will not be added like this, instead you will be using loops to add them. For simplicity I have added only 1 item.

Comment: Changed to clarify @TedLyngmo's question

Comment: It clearly needs to be dynamic since he reads the size from a file and that size is unknown. Why the `position` to `add()` when the `Map` has a `numEntries` member variable?

Comment: Okay, but the issue with this being: then data from both dictionary and employee are stored in the same arrays. How would I later access these separately? Second, when I insatiate domain and range I would need a size for the arrays. But both dictionary and employees are gonna have varying amount of data. How would I counteract this problem as well?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I want to be able to loop from 0-numEntries in my exec class and add data from the files using the add function in the map class.

Comment: They are not stored in the same arrays. As I said, for every set of template parameters you use with your class template, you create a new class - so the types of the members will be different. Check @formerlyknownas_463035818's answer. And if the size isn't known when you create an instance of the class, it'll have to be able to grow dynamically when the size gets known.

Comment: @FezPaudel you will be having separate maps for employee and word mappings. Hence you will not be sharing the arrays, they will be 2 different pairs of memory. Do understand, that templates are used to provide similar operations on different data types when the operations dont depend upon the type of data.